# Are there any differences in the implementation of file or list between OP , because my code worked on windows but not on Linux(Mac OS X)

Tags: c, list, file

My code works on a Windows PC but not on my Mac OS X. I m sure the code is correct, or at least this code works on windows.

My project is about a menu using structure and file ( adding point of interest , add a comment, printf info) and initially I implemented the binary file as function but then I re wrote them in the main to check if something changed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


//STRUCT WITH POI LIST

typedef struct {
    char title[20];
    char key[5];

} t_poi;

typedef struct _t_nodo_poi {
    t_poi poi;
    struct _t_nodo_poi *next;
}_t_nodo_poi;
typedef  _t_nodo_poi* ptr_nodo_poi;

typedef struct{

    ptr_nodo_poi head;
    ptr_nodo_poi tail;

}t_lista_poi;
typedef t_lista_poi* lista_poi;

//Inizialization of list
lista_poi new_lista_poi() {
    lista_poi new_list = malloc(sizeof (t_lista_poi));
    new_list->head = NULL;
    new_list->tail = NULL;
    return new_list;
}

//READ POI
t_poi read_poi() {

    t_poi poi;
    printf("Title POI: \n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s\n", poi.title); //NO NUMERI E CARATTERI SPECIALI
    printf("\nDescription POI: \n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", poi.key);
    return poi;
}

//INSERT POI IN THE LIST

int insert_poi(lista_poi _lista, t_poi _new_poi) {

    ptr_nodo_poi new_node = (ptr_nodo_poi) malloc(sizeof (_t_nodo_poi));
    if (new_node == NULL)
        return 0;

    new_node->poi = _new_poi;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if ((_lista)->head == NULL) {

        (_lista)->head = new_node;
        (_lista)->tail = new_node;
    } else {

        (_lista)->tail->next = new_node;
        (_lista)->tail = new_node;
    }
    return 1;
}

//SAVING FILE

void saving_file(lista_poi _lista, FILE * _file) {

    ptr_nodo_poi ptr = _lista->head;
    while(fwrite(&ptr->poi, sizeof(t_poi), 1, _file)) {


        ptr = ptr->next;
        printf("Check");
    }
}




int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int test,choice,check;
    t_poi new_poi;

    lista_poi _lista_poi;

    _lista_poi = new_lista_poi();

    FILE * file;

    file= fopen("saving", "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {

        printf("Failed");
        exit(1);

    }else{

        while (fread(&new_poi ,sizeof(t_poi),1, file)) {

            insert_poi(_lista_poi,new_poi);

        }
        fclose(file);
}
        do{
        printf("Choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:

                printf("Insert new POI:");
                new_poi = read_poi();
                test = insert_poi(_lista_poi, new_poi);
                if (test == 0)
                    printf("Error memory");
                else
                    printf("Inserted succesfully");


                break;

                case 2:

                printf("Saving on file\n");

                if (_lista_poi->head != NULL) {
                    file = fopen("saving", "wb");
                    printf("\nCheck");

                    if (file==NULL) {

                        printf("\nFailed");
                        exit(1);

                    }else{

                        saving_file(_lista_poi, file);
                        fclose(file);
                    }

                }else
                    printf("List empty!");


                printf("EXIT FROM PROGRAM");

            default:
                break;
        }
 } while (choice != 2);
}
```

Right now it doesn't give me any error but it doesn't save anything either and when I had the loading and saving of file as function it gave me an Exception about allocated memory and it pointed me at line mentioned in the Code.

EDIT: I guess now you can copy/paste... and by the way this code on Xcode give me exit code 1 saying that the file is NULL

Comment: `"wb"` is not valid on anything but Windows.

Comment: Please read through how to make a [mcve] and do that. It isn't an issue of whether the code is readable, it is incomplete and nobody can copy/paste it then compile/run it. Personally I'm not going to try and piece it together when it is in chunks, but it is often the case where the code you left out because you thought it wasn't the problem is the code that is the problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It should be fine now

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file twice:

```
file= fopen("saving", "rb");

file = fopen("saving", "wb");
```

There are a few things you need to do:

1. Change the first to `file = fopen("saving", "w+b");`.
2. Remove the second `fopen`
3. Move the `fclose` down to the end of the program

Then your code should be fine.